# How to extern declare an extern "C" variable

Tags: c++, dll

I wants to export a global variable from dll I define the global variable like below. Assume this variable is defined in A.cpp

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int A;
```

Meanwhile, within the dll, another source file B.cpp wants to use and modify this value. I am wonderring how to declare the variable within B.cpp before using it.

```
extern "C" int A; ?
```

If in this case, how does compile recognize between declare and definition?

```
extern extern "C" int A; ?
```

It's definitely ill-formed.

Comment: Use a header file?

Comment: @Chnossos, can you show me the detail structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [basic.def]/2.2, a declaration of an object at namespace scope is a definition unless:

> it contains the `extern` specifier (9.2.1) or a *linkage-specification*<sup>19</sup> (9.11) and neither an *initializer* nor a *function-body*,
> ...
> <sup>19</sup> Appearing inside the brace-enclosed *declaration-seq* in a *linkage-specification* does not affect whether a declaration is a definition.

Thus:

`extern "C" int A;` is a declaration.

`extern "C" int A = 0;` is a definition.

The below defines `A` and `B`, and declares `C`: the effect is the same as it would be without the `extern "C"` block, except that the entities declared have C linkage instead of C++ linkage.

```
extern "C" {
    int A;
    extern int B = 0;
    extern int C;
}
```

Comment: This answer is best because it points out that the `extern "C"` linkage specification already turns the grammar into a declaration just like `extern` alone; it is not necessary to repeat `extern` to get the effect.

Answer (score 1):

> `extern extern "C" int A; ?`

`extern "C"` can be used as a block:

```
extern "C"
{
    extern int A;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration needs to be in a header file like A.h or other code files cannot use it. The dllexport is especially useless without a header file. You probably want some kind of DLLEXPORT macro so you can define it to dllexport and dllimport as necessary. See pretty much any Windows DLL code.

Then in a cpp file you include the header. That allows your code to use the variable which is declared `extern`.

In **one** of your cpp files you include the header **AND** then define the variable using the same type and name and no extern. The linker will then put the data storage for it into the same module as the rest of that cpp file and all other uses of the name get linked to that definition.

However, just like private member variables in C++ it is a bad idea to expose global variables in a DLL. It is much better to hide access to them behind function calls.